# Linking error related to libcurl while building azure-iot-sdk-c sample code

Tags: cmake, ld, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I was facing an issue while building azure-iot-sdk-c sample code  with  below toolchain.cmake configuration.

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   arm-linux-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR /curl_path/include/)
SET(CURL_LIBRARY /curl_path/lib/libcurl.so)
```

Below is the error which I am getting on console:

```
/sysroot/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

During the compilation of azure-sdk libraries cmake is taking CURL_INCLUDE_DIR and CURL_LIBRARY path as expected. but during the building of sample code, which present inside azure-sdk repo, it is `failing with -lcurl not found error`. This issue is due to CMake is looking into the wrong directory (i.e `sysroot/usr/lib/`) instead of searching libcurl. so inside `CURL_LIBRARY` passed from toolchain.cmake.

How i can make `CMake` to look into `CURL_LIBRARY` directory for linking of sample code binaries to resolve this issue?

Comment: How is your CMake linking with the curl library? Is CMake calling `find_library()` or some other command to locate the curl library (which may use or overwrite the `CURL_LIBRARY` variable you have defined)? Please show the rest of your CMake code.

Comment: @squareskittles cmakelist.txt code added

Comment: Please also post the CMake code in which you **link** your targets to the curl library. I.e. a call to `target_link_libraries()` or similar. If your `find_package()` call is run, the `CURL_LIBRARIES` variable should contain the path to your curl library.

Comment: @squareskittles edited with target_link_libraries

Comment: @squareskittles also i was thinking as this issue related to ld , there should be some flags or some way to tell linker to look for libcurl in particular path that should be set from toolchain.cmake file .any idea on this ?

Comment: I don't think it's common practice to set library-specific information in the toolchain file. It's best to set all this in your top-level CMake, or even better, set it in the curl libraries section of CMake code you posted. You have not provided enough information to understand what is going on. Consider reading through and providing information to compose a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Such information would include the *full* CMake output, *full* `make` error log, CMake version, etc.

Comment: @squareskittles do you know any way i can make cmake to stop linking with default lcurl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was because in azure-iot-sdk sample code they are directly referring curl library before finding curl package .which is something like  `find_package(CURL)` they should be doing before `target_link_libraries(azure_sample_bin lcurl)` .
i was able to fix it adding below code inside `azure-iot-sdk-c/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library( curl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET curl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CURL_LIBRARY}")
```

Also this issue can be avoided if we stop building sample codes.This can be done by making `skip_samples=ON` .But even though this flag is `ON` by default inside `azure-iot-sdk-c/CMakeLists.txt` , it is not making any effect while building(may be beacuse this line of code is at wrong place ).we can still aviod building sample code by passing `skip_samples:BOOL=ON`  while running `cmake` as below

```
cmake "-Dskip_samples:BOOL=ON"  path_to_azure_sdk/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH in your cross compile toolchain file. There is a working example of a cross compile of the SDK, albeit performed in a Docker container, here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/samples/dockerbuilds/RaspberryPi/Dockerfile. This example also builds all the prerequisites.